# How do I change how many values put into vertex buffers in opengl?

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl

I've recently been learning opengl via the tutorials on http://learnopengl.com/, but I've come to the issue that the array that you place into the GLbufferdata has to be of a fixed sized that you declare when you initialize. However in my program I want to have it such that a dynamic number of objects that can be created and deleted (done via a list) have parameters that appear on screen.

I've managed to make code that takes the data from the objects and converts it into and array of floats for the VBO and an array of integers for the EBO however these array can't seem to change size, so whilst my program can set the array to the correct size depending on how many objects there are to begin with I can't re-declare the array meaning that if I wanted to add more objects they would not be rendered.

I could of course set the array to be bigger than I need it, but that seems to be inefficient and circumventing the issue.

Thanks for the help, by the way :).

Edit: [Here](http://pastebin.com/nMKurSXE) is a link to a more condensed version which should help outline the issue more concisely. Line 99/100 is where I create the array, however nothing shows up when compiled.

Comment: Can't you dynamically allocate the arrays using `new`? What do you mean by "can't re-declare the array"? Just free the old memory and allocate new.

Comment: Problem with that is that you need to pass a pointer to the array then, which then doesn't work for some reason, none of the vertices are drawn. I may be doing it wrong however, but I don't see how (I managed to get normal pointed arrays working perfectly fine).

Comment: Then show the code, otherwise its hard to tell whats wrong here.

Comment: I've linked it in the main post. Basically what I did is replace the vertices array declaration with:
GLfloat * vertices;
vertices = new GLfloat[allverts.size()];
Which produced no errors, but nothing but the background appeared on screen.

Comment: @Nesou2: You should add _the relevant parts_ of the code directly to the question. Provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have made another link which outlines my problem in a much more simple program. If you swap lines 99/100 for a simple declaration of a fixed size array then the program works as intended.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't sure, but I think that you can't dynamically change vertex buffer size after declaration (you can remove buffer and create one more which will be have needed size).

Better way is each object in your system must have own vertex buffer.

Comment: Every glBufferData call allocates the memory if necessary and thus can change the size of the buffer

Comment: @BDL Do you mean that I can call glBufferData twice? The first time I can allocate memory for 10 objects and second time for 20 objects without removing buffer?

Comment: I take it that would entail looping through every vao and binding them in turn and then running the shader? I take it I would make a list of anonymous GLuints which I then iterate through every game tick. Then if I want to delete an object I would simply remove it from the list when It would be deleted. Is that right?

Comment: @Nesou2 Yes. I think so.

Comment: @Nesou2 To delete something you also need to call glDeleteBuffers to free the gpu side memory.